# Java method queue performance

Tags: java, performance, scheduler

I am writing client-server app, and before i will take care about connection thread/main loop synch, i must ask a question.
If, all connections will store Method reference in queue, and main loop will invoke this methods, how bad can it slow down my app? (This solution will make thread-safe really easy).

This is my scheduler clas:

```
public class Scheduler 
{
    private static class Task
    {
        Method method;
        Object[] params;
        Object object;

        Task(Method _met, Object _object, Object[] _params)
        {
            method = _met;
            object = _object;
            params = _params;
        }
    }

    private static final ConcurrentLinkedQueue<Task> queue;

    static
    {
        queue = new ConcurrentLinkedQueue<Task>();
    }

    public synchronized static void addTask(Method action, Object obj, Object[] params)
    {
        queue.add(new Task(action, obj, params));
    }

    synchronized static void execute()
    {
        Task task;
        while(!queue.isEmpty())
        {
            try
            {
                while(!queue.isEmpty())
                {
                    task = queue.poll();
                    task.method.invoke(task.object, task.params);
                }
            }
            catch(IllegalAccessException ex)
            {
                 Logger.getLogger(Protocol.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            } catch (IllegalArgumentException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(Protocol.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            } catch (InvocationTargetException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(Protocol.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
            finally
            {

            }
        }
    }
}
```

So will be it to slow for 100 threads (all instance has own scheduler, main loop will be execute them all in loop).

Comment: Simple answer: we don't know. Measure it and come back if it is not acceptable. Just a tip, I would remove the `synchronized` from the `addTask` method, because your `queue` is already lock-free synchronized internally (which will be faster).

Comment: `execute` shouldn't be `synchronized` as well for the same reason.

Comment: Initialize your variable at the proper place, i.e., in the declaration directly.

Answer (score 0):

Just one thing to point out: if you have `static synchronized` method, then it doesn't matter how many instances of `Task` you have because `static synchronized` will put lock on class rather than `this` (instance)